# Can I use my Schengen visa for multiple purposes

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry

I was issued a Schengen visa for 90 days validity with multiple entry.
Initially I planned for tourism to France and Switzerland and accordingly I have written the purpose as tourism only and I will be travelling as well for a week and coming back to India. First I am using for tourism for one week and travelling back to India.

Now, I also need to travel again to Schengen area to the same countries for business purpose for one week again. Can I use the same visa or do I need to get a new one?

Comment: Why would you need to reapply if you have a multiple entry visa that you have / will have used for the originally stated purpose and that is valid for all your intended travel dates?

Comment: @Traveller OP's originally stated purpose was tourism, they now want to make a second trip for a different purpose - business. OP is concerned that the visa may be valid for tourism only.

Comment: Connected question, seems asked by the same person.https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141192/can-i-use-schengan-visa-issued-for-tourism-for-business-purpose?noredirect=1

Comment: Note that "visa" is just an ordinary word and doesn't need to be written all in caps.