# Can I use Schengen visa issued for tourism for business purpose

Tags: schengen

I am from India and I have applied for Schengen visa for tourism purpose only (France and Switzerland) and it was issued for 90 days validity with multiple entry. First i am also travelling for tourism purpose only and return back to India.

Now, I need to travel for same countries again (of course within the validity of visa), but for business purpose. Can I use the same visa or do I need to re-apply again for business reason separately?

Appreciate if someone could clarify my doubt urgently.

Comment: Please do not ask again if you do not (yet) have an answer. This site does not allow that. You can edit your earlier question with extra details and it helps getting attention to it as well. And please do stick to the one account.

Comment: And please stop writing "visa" in capital letters.